# Foreach of TWO Looping TextFields, possible?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach, nested-loops

```
    /* Adding Experiences */
$("#addExperience").click(function () {

if(experiencectr>5){
        alert("WOW! But 5 experiences are enough.");
        return false;
}   

var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
     .attr("id", 'ExperienceDiv' + experiencectr);

newTextBoxDiv.html('<label>Experience No. '+ experiencectr + ' : </label>' +
      '<input type="text" name="experience[]" id="experience' + experiencectr + '" >&nbsp;' +
      '<input type="text" id="year' + experiencectr +
      '" size="5" name="years[]"><label>years</label>');

newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#ExperienceBoxesGroup");


experiencectr++;
 });
```

In the code above, It adds two fields: experience and years textfields

```
    foreach ($_POST['experience'] as $experience) {
// save $experience to database
$sql_experience = "INSERT INTO experiences(number,experience)
values ('$number','$experience')";
if($result3 = mysql_query($sql_experience ,$db))
    {
            foreach ($_POST['years'] as $years) {
            $sql_years = "UPDATE experiences SET years=$years WHERE experience=$experience";
            if($result = mysql_query($sql_years ,$db))
                { }
            else 
                { echo "ERROR: ".mysql_error(); }
            }
    }
else 
    { echo "ERROR: ".mysql_error(); }
}
```

In this code above, it saves into database but the field columns have the SAME value in all rows. Can you guys please help me?

I need an answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the indexes to access the values in the other array:

```
foreach($_POST['experiences'] as $idx => $experience) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO experiences (number, experience, years)
            VALUES ({$idx}, {$experience}, {$_POST['years'][$idx]}");
    // execute query, etc
}
```

This will work, but you probably shouldn't do it this way because it leaves you open for [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). A better way to do this would be by sanitizing your inputs (eg: [`mysql_reaL_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) or its mysqli equivalent)

The best way to go would be [using prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php):

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO experiences (number, experience, years) 
                       VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

foreach($_POST['experiences'] as $idx => $experience) {
    // pass values and execute
    $stmt->execute(array($idx, $experience, $_POST['years'][$idx]));
}
```

Comment: sorry copied and paste the second code but i got an error : `Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO experiences (number, experience, years) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");`. uhm what will i do? i', not really that good in here :)