# Combine Two Column Fields From ONE Table

Tags: php, mysql, join

I made a new question cause I don't understand the other answers.

I want to get clear here.


I have a table named "experiences".

It has THREE FIELDS: id, experience_name, years.

I want to combine the TWO COLUMNS : experience_name and year and name it like.. experience 
Then i want to make a new table and name it resume_experiences and put the COLUMNS id and experience

can you guys please help me..

How am i gonna do it?

OUTPUT SHOULD BE: 
table name: resume_experiences 
fields: ID | EXPERIENCE

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303768/foreach-of-two-looping-textfields-possible/7303825#7303825

Comment: why did you give that url? they're different questions.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you elaborate, with examples?

Comment: I took from your profile. If you do not understand your previous question's answer, I think you should include details as much as possible. The above question is ambiguous.

Comment: i'm sorry :) i understand the answers from my previous question.. they all got answered correctly. It's the questions & answers of other posts that i don't understand.. that's why i post my own question. sorry about that :)

Comment: just so you guys would know. i don't know anything about mysql and i'm sorry for repeating my questions. :( Bye

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO resume_experiences
(id, experience)
SELECT id, CONCAT(experience_name, ' ', CONVERT(years,UNSIGNED))
FROM experiences
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `resume_experiences `
SELECT `id`, CONCAT(`experience_name`, ' ', `years`) AS `experience`
FROM `experiences`;
```